# Mongoid query! Combination of limit and order

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

In my rails app I want to grab the 10 last records with a unique value.

I tried:

```
@users = User.all(:limit => 10, :sort => [:created_at, :desc]).map{|t| t.first_name}.uniq
```

but,

the limit doesn't work as I expect..

I want the 'limit' to effect the query last.

any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@users = User.desc(:created_at).limit(10).map(&:first_name).uniq
```

You should use `distinct`. It is possible that `uniq` will cause you to get fewer than 10 records.

```
@users = User.limit(10).distinct(:first_name).desc(:created_at).map(&:first_name)
```

Comment: Actually the problem is that I am getting fewer than 10 with uniq.
The second line, unfortunately, gives: undefined method `limit' for []:Array

Comment: @vic: the ordering of methods was probably wrong. I can't test at the moment. Try the edited version. http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#limit

Comment: It seems that @users = User.limit(10).desc(:created_at).distinct(:first_name) almost works! But ignores the sort order 'desc'..Also tried order_by([:created_at, :desc])..but doesn't sort..Thanks for your time!